# see physical SQL in oracle analytics cloud reports

Tags: oracle, oracle-analytics, oracle-analytics-cloud

We are using Oracle Analytics Cloud. I have admin role. But i can not see physical sql in session log. I can see logical SQL and query run stats etc.

I checked sesion log - it more or less look like below.

> -------------------- SQL Request, logical request hash:
> cse759a5
> SET VARIABLE QUERY_SRC_CD='Report'...
> SELECT
> saw_0,
> saw_1,
> saw_2,
> saw_3,
> <>
> ------ General Query Info: [[]]
> Query Status: Successful Completion
> Rows 47052, bytes 1163125440 retrieved from database query id: <<145>>, physical request hash dadb8a
> Physical query response: Total time 36.572 (seconds), Fetch time 4.417 (seconds), Execute time 32.153 (seconds), id
> Physical Query Summary Stats: Number of physical queries 1, Cumulative time 36.572, DB-connect time 0.000 (seconds)
> Rows returned to Client 47052
> Logical Query Summary Stats: Elapsed time 93.484, Total time in BI Server 89.400, Execution time 88.569, Response time 109.939, Compilation time 52.191 (seconds), logical request hash 640...
>
> - Num of Result Cache Hit:0, Num of XSA Cache Hit:0.
> - Deferred init block execution time for logical request hash e6c759a5 : 0.000 (seconds)

Session log doesnt have any physical SQL which is i am interested.
Target DB - Oracle DB

Comment: 1.) That can't be the full log, 2.) What logging level are you running at right now? 3.) Is that in classic analytics or in DV?

Comment: 1- It isnt full log. I just removed actual logical SQL. 2- not sure but i think its full one 10 or something. 3 - classic analytics with rpd etc. Not data visualization.

Comment: There is no log level 10. You have to verify which log level you're running at the moment instead of working with assumptions: https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/obis/loglevel

Comment: @Chris, thank you. i need some time to answer that. Need to check with Admin. I can see the log for some reports. It seems union reports arent generating SQLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable [Developer Options](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/analytics-cloud/acubi/developer-reference.html#GUID-5A0BD6CE-EEB3-4028-B64C-BE3178B69C21) in OAC, from a Workbook you can click the Workbook Menu (three-dots in right-hand corner of workbook) and select "Developer". Among other features, this will allow you to view the Logical SQL and Queries generated by your report.

If this is not sufficient, [Usage Tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/analytics-cloud/tutorial-set-up-usage-tracking/index.html#before_you_begin) in OAC can be set-up to analyze queries in greater detail (i.e. which queries may be creating performance bottlenecks).

Comment: thank you for your answer. This report is an UNION report and it seems thats causing some issue in seeing physical SQL. logical SQL is not needed for me. So we took your second route of getting SQL from usage tracking. Thank you.